# How to get the node title of a refernced node

Tags: 7, entities, tokens, nodes

I'm using Drupal 7, and trying to work some magic from within a hook_node_presave() function.

I have a node reference field, and I'm trying to get the name of the referenced node rather than nid. When I trace out the field (`$node->field_my_name`) I get the following

```
Array
(
    [und] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [nid] => 23
                )

        )

)
```

I wondering if there is a way to get the title without doing a full load of the referenced node. Is there anyway I can do this with a token? Would this no be an issue if I were using entity reference rather than references?

Comment: more than likely, the node is cached anyway and node_load(23) won't too adversely effect performance.

Comment: good point, I'm just really surprised that there is no function to load the title of a node, give the nid, I just tried to do it with a static query, but for some reason it didn't work

Answer (score 1):

You could use [entity_label()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!common.inc/function/entity_label/7) function.

The function takes the entire entity as an argument, and it should already be loaded.
I would just load the node. As the other author suggested, it is very likely to be already cached in a `hook_node_presave()` call.